# node user directory leading to command not found

Tags: node.js, command-line, terminal, npm

I suipidly ran this [script](https://github.com/glenpike/npm-g_nosudo) to stop having to use sudo on `npm -g` commands and now my node_modules are located at:
`/Users/myusername/.npm-packages/lib/node_modules`

when trying to run a commands i.e `yo` `bower` i get `-bash: bower: command not found`

Do I need to link this directory to the usr/bin?

In trying to sort this out I have run lots of commands and created symbolic links, I feel like my system is a real mess and I cannot really see what is going on? Help to ensure my system is clean would be really helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally, it's a good idea to ensure that you do not need admin rights to run npm commands. The problem you're having, is that the directory where npm now installs its commmands (`/Users/myusername/.npm-packges/bin`) is not in your PATH. Your PATH is a list of directories where your shell searches for the commands you type.

You can add the directory to your path by adding the following line to the `.bashrc` file in your home directory (create it if it doesn't exist).

`export PATH="${PATH}:/Users/myusername/.npm-packages/bin"`

Open a new terminal, and bower should work again.

As an additional tip, I believe you're running on OS X? When installing Node.js using [Homebrew](http://brew.sh/), it is automatically installed in a proper way (no sudo needed to install packages globally and they will just work). Next time you're installing Node.js (or something else), Homebrew might be worth a try.

Comment: How can I undo what the script did so I can start again fresh?

Comment: For your own reference can get show a list of your currently installed global packages (`npm list -g --depth=0`), delete the folder the script created (`rm -r ~/.npm-packages`), reset the location where npm installs global packages (`npm config delete prefix`) and then reinstal your global packages (`npm install -g ...`).